# Can I use JSONObject instead of HashMap in Java?

Tags: java

I am doing an application which has a server and web, native clients. Whenever a request comes from any of the client server should do the following:

1. Fetch the data/model
2. For webclient request create a html page by compiling the corresponding JSP page or else for native-client request simply fetches the data alone.

Generally I fetch the data and put it into an `HashMap` and pass it to the JSP page. But for native requests I am planning to return the data in json format. Here my doubt is instead of having data in different objects(`HashMap` and `JSONObject`), can I use the `JSONObject` for both purposes?. Will there be any performance implications when I use `JSONObject` instead of `HashMap`?.

Comment: As for the performance implications: why not profile that? There _might_ be a performance hit but unless you serialize/deserialize the JSONObject it should be neglectible. The more sensible question would be: is using JSONObject even when you're not using the JSON functionality going to increase readability/maintainability? Using JSONObject would imply you need the JSON functionality, which you don't always do. SOme other questions: why are you planning to use JSON? What are _native_ requests in your context? Is the data being serialized in those cases?

Answer (score 0):

There will be not that much differentce, because most implementations of JSON are backed by maps. Better solution ( from JSP point of view )  would be using java beans, and convert your JSON  / other data source  to objects using some databinding  solution

Answer (score 0):

From a software engineering perspective, you should not use a view-specific data types in other layers like persistance layer in your example.